# Adobe Air - Invalid Bundle structure. Your app may contain only one executable file

Tags: ios, xcode, air, app-store, adobe

We have a game created with Adobe Air. We've built app-store version and we have these errors:

[image: errors]

We even have this problem with previous build that was already approved by Apple.

Does anybody have any idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Same problem with my homeMade ANE (for advert) that i use in many project without problem.

I resolved the issue by removing the Xcode static librairy from my prodiver in my ANE compiling script. The static library is now only include in my Nativ Xcode project.

Hope it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your library files (`libKontagentAne.a`, `libAirFacebook.a`, etc.) are being copied to the App bundle in a **Copy Bundle Resources** build phase. They should instead be linked.

We have seen this same issue from some developers  integrating the [Apptentive iOS SDK](https://github.com/apptentive/apptentive-ios/).

`Invalid Build Structure`

`The binary file 'YourApp.app/libApptentiveConnect.a' is not permitted.`

`Your app may contain only one executable file."`

This error occurs when the Apptentive static library is copied to the app bundle.

`libApptentiveConnect.a` should be added to the target's **Link Binary with Libraries** Build Phase.

It should **not** be added to the target's **Copy Bundle Resources** build phase.